# Perform manual test, automate after - or never?

Tags: testing

In my current company, we have one tester. Having spoken to this tester, she says that in testing, before implementing any automation systems, the scripts (steps to take) are manually written and performed (performed at least once).

Is this the way things work in testing?

To make me laugh, this has been done in this case, yet no automation. It makes me laugh to see the lead tester perform loads of different combinations of usernames and passwords for a login form (which she is not overly keen on having automated) when I could easily automate that (but politics in the company won't allow that).

This doesn't seem like the environment where a junior tester (not me, I'm a SDET) cannot learn anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different testers work in different ways.  Trying hundreds of username/password combinations is probably grounds for automation.  However, if your releases come out once every one or two weeks then manually testing 10-20 username/password combinations isn't out of the question.  My current group has 6 testers.  4 of them primarily do manual-exploratory testing while the other 2 work on automation tools.

Comment: Your last sentence implies that there is some real structure in the team. The release is in rescoping for the 2nd time after just 3 weeks. It's just embarassing to be confident in my skills and then work with people who don't see a problem doing things in such a low-tech way. I doubt all the bugs that can be possibly caught (and the code quality is VERY poor, I've reviewed it) will be caught.

Comment: @dotnetdev, what stops you from starting a test harness on your own computer every night, running whatever tests you write? You could add a project called "Tools", "Util", "Seaweed Salad", etc. which actually contain tests. The test framework can then send email results to you alone. Spend a few Saturdays and you should be all set. Yes, it sounds counter-productive to test everything manually at least once. Exploratory testing is very important. Predictable tests are better automated from the start.

Comment: The quality of the team I am in and company politics. I have given up and just concentrate on myself now.